# (-2)*loglikelihood ~ Chi-square?

Tags: asymptotics, chi-squared, log-likelihood

I just vaguely remember that I have learned something like
"(-2)*loglikelihood asymptotically follows Chi-square distribution."

However, I failed to find the relevant theorems in the textbook.
Does anyone know the right theorem for this?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Wilks' theorem. It says that minus twice the logarithm of a maximum likelihood ratio statistic asymptotically approaches the chi-squared distribution as the sample size approaches infinity. Take a look at [this](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177732360).